# signInWithEmailAndPassword not working on IOS app only React Native Firebase

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, react-native

I have this react native project where a user has to sign up and then verify their email to get into the app. Once a user signs up it creates an account and then sends a verification email. The user is promoted with two buttons, "I verified my email" "Try again". If they have not verified their email, the following function returns `Alert.alert("Your email isn't verified", "Please make sure to click the link sent to the email you signed up with.")`

```
setStatus('checkEmail function ran')
            auth.signOut()
                .then(() => {
                    setStatus('Started signin')
                    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                        .then((userCredential) => {
                            setStatus('Started user creds')
                            const user = userCredential.user;
                            user.reload()
                                .then(async () => {
                                    setStatus('User reloaded')
                                    if (user.emailVerified) {
                                        try {
                                            navigation.replace('Main');
                                        } catch (error) {
                                            Alert.alert(`ERROR: ${error}`)
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Alert.alert("Your email isn't verified", "Please make sure to click the link sent to the email you signed up with.")
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    Alert.alert('ERROR', error);
                                });
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            Alert.alert('ERROR', error);
                        });

                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    Alert.alert('ERROR', error);
                });
```

BUT if the user is emailVerfied the IOS app crashes right after `setStatus('Started signin')` (so in the signIn part i believe). I cannot replicate this error on expo and it works perfectly fine on Expo Go, but it happens on IOS and Testflight.

I have tried many different things, but nothing resolves the issue. None of the .catch functions catch an error, and the app simply crashes. I can't replicate the error on Expo Go, so I don't really no what to do.

Comment: Look in the testflight console to see if you have a crash report. The exception message may provide a clue

Comment: @Paulw11 where do i find the testflight console

Comment: AppStore connect, under TestFlight for your app, look for crashes